# Overflow right column to fill remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have a layout where the top header should have 100%, and content has two content columns. Left column should take up remaining vertical space, and right column will overflow however the height should also take up remaining vertical space (same as the left element).

html:

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="header">
            header
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="right">
              <div>right</div>
--            omitted a lot of repeating rows here which are needed to create overflow
              <div>right</div>
              <div>right</div>
              <div>right</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```
    html, body {
      height: 100%
    }

    .wrap {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .content {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .left {
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: #d5f4e6;
    }

    .right {
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: #d504e6;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

I have it mostly working, but the right column height is slightly taller than the left element (by the height of the header for some reason). Open my codepen https://codepen.io/ilikepure/pen/MWajBYY
 link and scroll the bottom right i-frame all the way down to see the weird effect.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: remove position: absolute and left: 50%

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `position: absolute` on the `.right` element. Not sure why you have that in a flex layout:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #d5f4e6;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #d504e6;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
      <div>right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```